# Clarification Regarding to prove diagonalisable operator iff Minimal Polynomial Splits and

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation, minimal-polynomials

I wanted to prove that A is diagonalisable over F iff minimal Polynomial of A splits over F and Have square free terms.
In that proof, I had following doubts
If A is diagonalisable then it is clear that A Has characteristics polynomial which splits over F.
As Minimal Polynomial of A divide characteristics polynomial of A.
 Then it also splits. Only thing remains to show that It has the square free term.
As A is diagonalisable it has eigenvalues then I wanted to show that
$m_T(x)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2).....(x-a_k)$ .
where $a_1,a_2,.....a_k $be eigenvalues . TO show this minimal polynomial I wanted to show that it Annihilates everything in Vector space.So take $v_i\in V$ such that $T(v_i)=a_iv_i$ Now consider above polynomial as 
$((T-a_1)(T-a_2).....(T-a_i)......(T-a_k)v_i=?$ Now I know that polynomial is commutative ring But How to think for this Because this is the operator. Is this also commutative.
If this I know it annihilates everything in V.
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable with distinct diagonal terms $d_1,\cdots,d_n$, then you can directly verify that $p(x)=(x-d_1)(x-d_2)(\cdots)(x-d_n)$ annihilates $A$. So the minimal polynomial has no repeated factors.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Sir ,I know that Polynomial is commutative ring but Can same result apply for Operator ? I had edited Question Please Help me

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable as $U^{-1}DU$, then $p(A)=U^{-1}p(D)p(U)$ and $p(D)=0$ if $p(x)=(x-d_1)(x-d_2)\cdots(x-d_n)$ where $d_j$ are the distinct diagonal elements of $D$. So the minimal polynomial has no repeated factors.